# How to execute 'service mongod start' using additional parameters in CentOS?

Tags: mongodb, centos

I unable to start MonogoDB service after adding users into admin db as well as my db.

I setup MonogoDB and started service using following command i.e.

`service mongod start`

Using command prompt, I added few users like dbOwner, clusterAdmin, readWrite, read roles base users. Along with that I also changed configuration from /etc/mongod.conf. in that file, I changed port number, IP addresses, dbPath, and security.authorization: enabled.

Then I restarted mongod service using following command.

`service mongod restart`

After ran this command, mongod service stopped successfully, but failed to start with only 'FAILED' message.

I tried execute following command i.e.

`mongod --port 27123 --dbpath /path/to/db --auth`

It is working.

Question: How to execute 'service mongod start' using additional parameters in CentOS?

MonogoDB: 3.4
OS: CentOS 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution i.e.

`mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Referred: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file

It starts child process and also I can stop mongod service using `service mongod stop` command.

But I don't know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: I checked with my few colleagues and it seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can't certify exactly where the script that "service" command uses on CentOS 7, but in Ubuntu 18.04 mongod service script file is in

```
/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

There you can change the user who executes the process and add any parameters you want, like --auth.

Said that, if you ever executed mongod as root, some files on where you store the db data will have the owner as root, making the database fail to start as another user. The fix I found for that is to manually chown to mongodb:mongodb (or the user you want to use) all the files that are owned by root inside the database.

Hope this helps.

[mongod.service file from mongodb github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/mongod.service)